# why can't I stretch the image to the full screen of the page?

Tags: html, css

I make a site and decided to make the background,wrote the code and viewing the page of the site realized that the image is not on the whole page

what do I need to fix to make the image stretch to the whole page?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>text</title>
        <style>
            body{
                  background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
                  -moz-background-size: 100%
                  -webkit-background-size: 100%
                  -o-background-size: 100%
                  background-size: 100%
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">
    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX7EJ.jpg)

Comment: your needed background-size: cover;

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `background-size: cover;` instead of 100%.

It resizes the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges